# Significance of difference in proportion

Tags: t-test, sample-size, proportion

I have a set of survey scores for different groups where each question in the survey has a binary outcome:

```
         Sample Size | I like apples | I like peaches | etc.
Group 1       3              66%               66%
Group 2      500             80%               95%
```

I am interested in how far from 100% each question scores.  In the example above, Group 1 might have a lower % in both cases, but the difference between 100% and 66% might be less significant than the 80% given the stark difference in sample size.

I want to evaluate the significance of the difference between 100% and each metric for each group.  I realize that `std_dev = sqrt(n*p*q)` but I'm not entirely sure how to use that to evaluate the delta between 100% and 66%.

Comment: Couldn't you just find confidence intervals (95% is typical) for each? Your sample size is much too small for Group 1, though.

Comment: Would confidence intervals go beyond the cap of 1?  Should they be on log-odds scale?  Are confidence intervals based on # of people who don't like apples or proportion?  I'm not sure exactly how to do this mechanically.

Comment: Confidence intervals are based on standard deviations. Under certain conditions, the sample proportion is normally distributed, so we can generate a 95% confidence interval by calculating $p\hat\pm1.96\sqrt{\frac{pq}{n}}$. You can logically cap this at 100%. Your first sample size is much too small, though. One guideline is you want $npq>10$ to use the normal approximation.

Comment: N=3 is just an example to demonstrate but I'm not interested in a binary outcome of rejecting a null hypothesis, I want a measure of how different from 100% each group is, normalizing for the sample size in the group.  So in this example, if N=3, the desired outcome would be that the difference from 100% for that group has a low significance value  (Chi-Squared?) since it's sample size is too low.

Comment: The idea was to see which interval was further from 100%, though I'm not sure that's the best solution. I'm also still not sure how to handle the low sample size. You say it's just for example, but then you reference it again. What about confidence intervals for the conplement - i.e. the difference from 100%? You can't do it with your example (n is too small), but it seems like a reasonable solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I want an interval, I want a metric that summarizes the significance of the observed difference (more like a Chi-square) and that statistic would ideally be robust enough to handle very low sample sizes (similar to a T-distribution) but my real data has group sizes that are greater than 5.  I wonder if a mixture model with a random effect for group size might help but that doesn't really get at the difference in proportion from 100%, just shrinks the estimate towards the mean when sample size approaches zero.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'll let others with more experience jump in. Sorry for leading down an unproductive track.

Comment: Oh no worries, you helped me quite a bit actually.  Thanks!